# UserControl, cursor at tabnavigation

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

In my window there are two `textbox` and my `usercontrol`.

[image: 1]

Once the cursor is `TextBox1`. When I click Tab cursor is in my `UserControl`, but cursor remains stable on `TextBox`(like `|` without blink). When I click next Tab cursor only in `TextBox2`. If I move cursor from `TextBox1` to my `usercontrol` - all right. The problem is in my component, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually set

- `TabIndex` of `TextBox1` to `1`;
- `TabIndex` of `TextBoxinUserControl` to `2`;
- `TabIndex` of `TextBox2` to `3`

`